# Scroll to a component when a button is clicked in React JSX

Tags: reactjs, scroll, components, jsx

I've looked at way too many ways to scroll to a certain component when clicking a button, but it's always in a JS file. Can't seem to get it to work in my JSX files project.

I've tried several libraries and methods such as "scrollTo", "scrollIntoView", "scrollToComponent"..
They pretty much all try to reference a component, but I can't seem to get it to work.
In JS it usually works when they use the "useRef" from react but, again, can't seem to do it in JSX.

Does anyone have any idea why and how to do it?

Something like:

```
const MyComponent = () => {

 const scrollSomewhere = () => {
     // PSEUDO-CODE - something along these lines maybe?
     // scrollToComponent("Somewhere");
 }

 return (
   <>
     <MyCustomButton onClick={scrollSomewhere}> Click me! </MyCustomButton >

     (...)

     <MyCustomComponent ref="Somewhere"> I'm somewhere </MyCustomComponent>

   </>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ref` needs to hold a reference the DOM element to which you want to scroll. Here's an example:

```css
.container {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.target {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  margin: 100rem 0;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.16.3/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="react">

const {useRef, useState} = React;

function Example () {
  const elementRef = useRef(null);

  const handleClick = () => {
    if (elementRef.current) {
      elementRef.current.scrollIntoView();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div>The element you want to scroll to is below </div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Scroll to element</button>
      <div className="target" ref={elementRef}>Here I am!</div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));

</script>
```

Comment: I've tried this before and did again but still this jsx and react version 16.8.0 says the scrollIntoView is not a function.
Thanks anyway tho